# Rails 7 fixtures for belongs_to relationship not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I'm having a problem with a RoR 7.0.6 app I'm developing

I have this migration:

```rb
class CreateClientes < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :clientes do |t|
      t.string :nombre
      t.string :nit
      t.string :direccion
      t.belongs_to :ciudad, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.text :etiquetas
      t.text :otros_nombres
      t.boolean :obsolete, default: false, null: false
      t.datetime :obsolete_at

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :clientes, :nombre
    add_index :clientes, :nit
  end
end
```

This is the cliente.rb model file:

```rb
class Cliente < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ciudad, optional: false
end
```

And this is the ciudad.rb model file:

```rb
class Ciudad < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :clientes, dependent: :restrict_with_error
end
```

This is clientes.yml fixtures file:

```yaml
one:
  nombre: Ingenieros Ingenieria
  nit: 900.000.000-1
  direccion: "Calle 1 # 1-1"
  ciudad: bogota
  etiquetas: "[]"
  otros_nombres: "[]"

two:
  nombre: Otro Cliente
  nit: 9004441112
  direccion: "Baker Street 221B"
  ciudad: medellin
  etiquetas: '["VIP"]'
  otros_nombres: '["El Cliente"]'
```

And this is the ciudades.yml fixtures file:

```yaml
bogota:
  nombre: Bogotá
  departamento: Cundinamarca

medellin:
  nombre: Medellín
  departamento: Antioquia
  codigo_dane: 05001
```

When I run `rails db:fixtures:load RAILS_ENV=test --trace` I get this error:

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "clientes" has no columns named "ciudad".

Tasks: TOP => db:fixtures:load
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

ciudades.yml is working properly. I know it because before creating the Cliente model all tests, including tests related to Ciudad, were passing.

What could be causing this problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: is your `Ciudad` table named `ciudades` or `ciudads`? It's possible that it's looking for `ciudads.yaml` when attempting to resolve `cidudad: bogota` in the fixture

Comment: the plural of Ciudad is ciudades, it is defined in the inflectors, the Ciudad table is named ciudades. ciudades.yml works fine, I know it because before creating Cliente model all tests passed, including Ciudad tests